# What is the significance of stdout[0] in relation to given script?

Tags: parsing, ansible

My question on `stdout[0]` is specific to below output. As i understand from ansible documentation, `stdout` means that it quotes the output of a variable and `[0]` means referencing the first char or command. I am just trying to figure out how the definition relates to what it does below.

The output of `show flash:` is stored in custom variable called show_flash shown below. 1st script below contains `.stdout[0]` after name of custom variable whereas 2nd script does not. I am trying to understand how `stdout[0]` affects the output the way it does given it's above meaning?
(I tried to 'code' the output but it didn't format properly)

**SCRIPT 1:**

```yaml
    - name: Pass text and template_path

      ansible.utils.cli_parse:
        text: "{{ show_flash.stdout[0] }}"
        parser:
          name: ansible.utils.ttp
          template_path: "templates/sample2.ttp"'''
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
TASK [Display facts]

ok: [ROUTER] => {

   "msg": [

        [
            {
            "flash:/": {
                "bytes_free": 22840320,
                "bytes_total": 122185728
```

**script 2:**

```yaml
  - name: Pass text and template_path
    ansible.utils.cli_parse:
      text: "{{ show_flash }}"
      parser:
      name: ansible.utils.ttp
      template_path: "templates/sample2.ttp"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
TASK [Display facts] 

ok: [ROUTER] => {

    "msg": [

    [
        {}
      ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I reformatted your code. Please take note that the character used to declare code blocks is the backtick (`) and not the single quote('). You should also review the result to make sure it is exactly as it is supposed to be and eventually fix any errors I could have introduced trying to fix it by editing your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for editing, the coide looks as i intended it to be. Thanks for backtick info as well.

Comment: Well then it is like you intended, it looks like there are indentation errors in script two which should prevent your code from running. Moreover, you should provide a debug output of the `show_flash` variable.

Comment: @Zeitounator can you please elaborate on wehat you mean by indentation error?   If there was error, the script would not have executed successfully. It would have rather ended with an error. In my case, script was successful but with blank output when i removed 'stdout[0]' from the script.

Comment: I beleive that in the second example `name` and `template_path` are not indented correctly...

Comment: @Zeitounator By indentation, i assume that you mean an empty space or extra space to right in those lines. Maybe my pasting here might have made it appear like an indentation issue but all i did was remove 'stdout[0]' from 2nd script with all other lines remaining intact.  So i don't think it might be indentation issue.

Comment: No need for long comments: just fix the code (edit your question) so it is correct (as I asked you to verify in my very first comment) if is already ok on your side and we stop wasting time. While you are at it, you still did not give a debug view of the `show_flash` var (already asked) and you should also probably provide the content of `templates/sample2.ttp`